# Regular expression that ignores HTML entities

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression in javascript which does the following.

Those instances of **a** which are not the part of an HTML entity, should be replaced with **w**.

Ex:

```
abc should change to wbc

aabacaa should change to wwbwcww

&amp;abcaa&amp; should change to &amp;wbcww&amp;
```

and so on.

I am using JavaScript.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to account for all HTML entities (like `&para;`)? Or just the `&amp;`. If you need to account  for  all, my answer is not the right one (and I will remove it).

Comment: what is the tool u wanted to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
"&amp;abcaa&amp;".replace(/&[^;]+;|a/g, function($0) {
    return $0 === "a" ? "w" : $0;
})
```

Comment: this won't convert    a&amp;b  to w&amp;b

Comment: @Varun: `replace` is not a mutator method. That means the original string the method is used on stays untouched. You need to assign the return value of `replace` to your variable if you want to change its value: `str = str.repalce(/* … */)`.

Answer (score 0):

a non-regex way, in your favourite programming language, split your string on "&a" (or `&amp;`), replace the splitted items , then join back eg in Python

```
>>> s="&amp;abcaa&amp;"
>>> '&a'.join( [ i.replace("a","w") for i in  s.split("&a") ] )
'&amp;wbcww&amp;'
```

Answer (score -1):

As a more general answer, when writing regular expressions, the first thing I do is to go to http://rubular.com and lay out a couple of test strings. I then write and re-work the regular expression until it does what I need.

Yes, I know Rubular is a Ruby regex site, but RegExp syntax is very similar, if not identical for most languages (I think Perl uses an extended syntax). I've successfully used Rubular to test Java RegExps.